# Angular project - Bootstrap, Angular material (+ Angular-Flex-Layout) or plain css/js

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

Next week the first sprint will start for the project I'm going to work on. We have decided to use Angular8 as a frontend framework, but we don't know for sure if we should make use of bootstrap, angular-material or just plain css.

I really need some advice in this matter, when to choose one or the other and why?

Comment: the decision must be between ng-bootstrap (that use bootstrap.css), Angular or another css. Depending you like material-angular controls or not

Comment: There is no functionality-related reason to choose one over other. Pick the one your developers are most familiar with and/or the one you think looks nicer. Plain css will require objectively more work to make it look good.

Comment: It's depends on how the design is of your project. Look into material and bootstrap and the available component in both and see which one fits better for your project. It's advise not to use plain css as it will be then time consuming to handle responsiveness of the system.

Comment: It depend on you first read all these framework a little bit then compare according to your needs then use it according to your ease. I would suggest you to use `angular-material ` as it follows latest trend and easy to use,

Comment: Your question is directly seeking opinions, and is therefore off topic for Stack Overflow. The question is also very broad, and you haven't provided any information about the nature of your project. Can you possibly reword it to ask a more focused and answerable question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That decision depends on the Project's requirements...**

If the UI / UX is very strict you might use css / scss, if not, just get advantage of [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/).

Regarding layout design, you can use [CSS-Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) / [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). They are very powerful and popular. It's very easy to design a layout using them. They don't give that automatic responsiveness from bootstrap because you have to do it manually using media-queries but it's still worth it !

Comment: What about angular + Angular Flex Layout? Isn't that a better choice than bootstrap?

Comment: updated my answer, was not very clear

Comment: "They don't give that automatic responsiveness from bootstrap because you have to do it manually using media-queries but it's still worth it !" In this case I could make use of Angular Flex Layout right?

Comment: Sure, you can even combine CSS-Grid and Flexbox. Have a look on the Doc, it's incredibly easy to do layouts with them.

Comment: So do you advise me to make use of Angular Material + Angular Flex layout? :)

Comment: Or should I think about using flexbox + css-grid in combination with angular material rather than Angular Flex Layout?

Comment: flex + grid + angular material.

Comment: please mark answer as valid if it was useful :)

Comment: Only if you could tell me why flex + grid and not angular-flex-layout : P

Comment: you can use grid for everything if you want, will work, but it's like, you can kill a bee with a bullet if you want, but personally I think that flex is nicer for simpler layouts and grid for advanced ones, and in some cases you might need to combine both. Anyway, if you feel confortable using only grid it's not a problem at all. Watch this ng-conf video by the way, you can see tons of examples using grid so you get familiar with it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh6n0JxXD_g

Comment: adding a nice article if you have doubts about how to combine css-grid and flex: https://css-tricks.com/things-ive-learned-css-grid-layout/